# Follow Individuals on Medium

Tags: medium

Is it possible for a reader to follow a particular writer/account on Medium.com?

If not, then why? What's the rationale behind not having such a basic feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the only things you can subscribe to (follow) on Medium are collections, and bookmark stories. Medium will notify you when there's an addition to your collections, or if a bookmarked story was edited.

If you go to your profile settings, you can Connect your Facebook account to see the stories your friends write and recommend - but that's the sum of it.

Finally, you can see what certain people publish and recommend in their personal page at https://medium.com/@twitter_handle.

My guesses as to why you can't follow specific writers are:

1. You can follow their twitter handle on twitter already, and see their page, as mentioned above.
2. They haven't gotten around to implementing it yet :).

Answer (score 2):

You can, just use an RSS feed aggregator: for instance, https://medium.com/feed/@aubreymcfato/ .

As far as I understand, the basic idea of medium.com is to push you to read stuff from random people so that everyone gets more pageviews and is more motivated to blog more.

The most obvious symptom is that they went back to the model "a single domain for everyone" which was common in the 1990s, as opposed to the more common "one (sub)domain for each blog" which has been prevalent since 2005 (see wordpress.com, blogger.com and even [livejournal.com](http://news.livejournal.com/90556.html)).

Some people even say [Medium is meant for collaborative writing, and not blogging](http://speckyboy.com/2013/12/20/disappointment-writing-medium-com/).